# C++ copy char to string

Tags: c++

```
int main()
     {
    string sample = "abcdef";
    string result; 
    result[0]='a';
    cout<<result[0];
    }
```

I am trying to copy a char into a string result;
the output should be a displayed. but there is no display.and no error message.

direct copy is working // result=sample;
how is this code wrong?

Comment: `result` is empty, so `result[0]` accesses the string out of bounds. `result += 'a';` or `result.push_back('a');` would work.

Comment: I understand the issue. result is a vector.and for all vector, if not initilized.the content inside is undefinded. another way to solve it is to add: result.resize(somesize); to initilize it.

Answer (score 4):

A few issues with your code:

1. (not a bug) Try not to use `using namespace std;`
2. `result` is initially empty so assigning to a specific character position will actually be a bug. If you append to it with the `+=` operator then it works as expected.
3. It should not be an issue but the std::cout buffer might not be flushed on some particular occasions. You can force to flush with `std::cout.flush()`.
4. Always end with a newline for clarity

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string sample = "abcdef";
    std::string result; 
    result +='a';
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Produces:

```cpp
Program returned: 0
Program stdout
a
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/ocvGP6333

Comment: Flushing the buffer is a confounding factor. It has no perceivable difference in the program's output. It confuses things and leads to cargo cult programming.

Comment: @JohnFilleau True!

Comment: Another option is to use `std::string result{sample};` first which will copy the sample string into result, then `result[0] = 'x';` is valid and will replace the first character in result while no changing the sample string.

Answer (score 3):

This should result in run time error while accessing

```
result[0]
```

hence you should use

```
 result+="a";
```

Also, you are not using sample variable in your code, if you intend to copy the first char from sample to result, you can use

```
int main() {
    string sample = "abcdef";
    string result; 
    result+=sample[0];
    cout<<result[0];
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that accessing a container out of bounds using `[index]` will generate an error. Using `at(index)` will generate an exception for out of range access.